Does the minimum Murmur3Partitioner token value -9223372036854775808 have a special meaning?
The cluster is using Murmur3Partitioner partitioner.
From the docs, the token range is -(2^63) to +(2^63-1); this translates to -9223372036854775808 ≤ token(id) ≤ 9223372036854775807
This is also the Java Long range.
The question is for token value -9223372036854775808, does it have special meaning? I try to query select * from table1 where token(key) = -9223372036854775808 and it gives me all the data.
Thanks!

The token doesn't have any special meaning, other than being the lowest value one.
You stumbled upon a Cassandra bug :)

Nice find, Mário! I had no idea about that one.

The value -9223372036854775808 is not a valid token for the Murmur3Partitioner because the partitioner uses this minimum value to select a range of data for a given token X.
In fact, this token gets "normalized" to the max Java Long value when used so when reading from a table using the minimum token as the filter, it "wraps around" the token ring and returns all the data (a full table scan).
Unfortunately, this behaviour isn't documented for users and is only known to project developers. There have been discussions on how to best deal with this quirk but it remains unresolved (CASSANDRA-16592, CASSANDRA-14684). Cheers!
